# Redundant private member data replication in implementation hierarchy

Tags: c++, design-patterns

My question concerns the combination of public and private inheritance as a tool to separate interface and implementation in a C++ class. In this pattern, the interface base class declares the common functions (`class Base0`). The common implementation is carried out in a class derived virtually from the interface base (`class Impl0 : virtual public Base0`). This class contains any common data members. The extension classes are written in two steps. First the extended interface is defined by virtual inheritance from the interface base (`class Base1 : virtual public Base0`). Second, the extended implementation is carried out by deriving publicly from `Base1` (for interface) and privately from `Impl0` (for implementation): `class Impl1 : public virtual Base1, private Impl0`. My questions are the following:

(1) if the functions in the extension class define functions that require common data in `Impl0`, do I have to replicate that data in `Impl1'?

(2) Is there any way to avoid this replication?

As a minimal example, consider a class hierarchy for implementing the four basic arithmetic functions: add(), substr(), mult() and div(). The basic version, `MathOps`, contains the add() and subtr() functions. The extended version, `MathOps_Extn`, contains mult() and div(). The above technique gives the following class hierarchy.

```
#include<iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class MathOps {
public:
  virtual int add(int x) = 0;
  virtual int subtr(int x) = 0;
};

class MathOps_Impl : public virtual MathOps {
private:
  int m_y;
public:
  MathOps_Impl(int y) : m_y(y) {
    cout << "MathOps_Impl initialized with value: " << m_y << endl;
  }

  virtual int add(int x) { return x + m_y;}
  virtual int subtr (int x) { return m_y - x;}
};

class MathOps_Extn  : public virtual MathOps {
  // Extends MathOps by adding mult() and div()                                                                                                                                 
public:
  virtual int mult(int x) = 0;
  virtual int div(int x) = 0;
};

class MathOps_Extn_Impl : public    virtual MathOps_Extn, private MathOps_Impl {
private:
  int m_y; // Have to replicate member data m_y here.                                                                                                                           
public:
  MathOps_Extn_Impl(int y) : MathOps_Impl(y), m_y(y) {
    cout << "MathOps_Extn_Impl initialized with value: " << m_y << endl;
  }

  virtual int mult(int x) {
    return x * m_y;
  }
  virtual int div(int x) {
    int quotient = x == 0? 0 : m_y/x;
    return quotient;
  }
};

int main() {                                                                                                                                           
  MathOps_Extn* B =  new MathOps_Extn_Impl(10);
  cout << "add 20: " << B->add(20) << endl;
  cout << "subtr 20: " << B->subtr(20) << endl;
  cout << "mult 2: " << B->mult(2) << endl;
  cout << "div 5: " << B->div(5) << endl;
```

Note the replication of `m_y` in `MathOps_Extn_Impl`. Is there any way to avoid this replication?

Comment: Who would want to fit arithmetic operations into an hierarchical design?

Comment: go another step and have a MathOps_Extn_base? Or put m_y in MathOps

Comment: Why won't you use `protected`? But if you want to have inheritance with `private` modifier, then yes you have to duplicate it. Putting `m_y` in interfaces without changing `private` to `protected` won't change too much.
Edit: about the first question, look how lookup for names works in C++. If you put `m_y` as protected in `Impl0` then you should be able to use it in `Impl1`.

Comment: @PiotrJaszkowski Thanks. I came to the same conclusion while reading through other answers on SO (that I didnt come across before posting my question). However, wont making `m_y` `protected` allow direct access to it for any (client) class that derives from `MathOps_Impl` (and hence break encapsulation) ?

Comment: @K-ballo I hope you are serious about your question. It is a minimal example to explain my question.

Comment: @RDK: Glad to hear its only an example. We've seen too many things hammered into a hierarchical design...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give access to the common data, without breaking encapsulation, via protected member functions in the common implementation class.

Gratuitous example follows :)

```
#include <cstdio>

class Math
{
public:
    virtual ~Math() {}
    virtual int add(int b) const = 0;
};

class MoreMath : public virtual Math
{
public:
    virtual ~MoreMath() {}
    virtual int subtract(int b) const = 0;
};

class MathImpl : public virtual Math
{
private:
    int m_a;

public:
    MathImpl(int a) : m_a(a) {}
    virtual ~MathImpl() {}
    int add(int b) const { return m_a + b; }

protected:
    int value() const { return m_a; }
};

class MoreMathImpl : public virtual MoreMath, private MathImpl
{
public:
    MoreMathImpl(int a) : MathImpl(a) {}
    int subtract(int b) const { return value() - b; }
};

int main()
{
    MoreMath* one = new MoreMathImpl(1);
    printf("1 + 2 = %d\n", one->add(2));
    printf("1 - 2 = %d\n", one->subtract(2));
    delete one;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have accepted your answer since it avoids protected member data.

Answer (score 1):

> Note the replication of m_y in MathOps_Extn_Impl. Is there any way to
>   avoid this replication?

Yes.  Give `MathOps_Impl::m_y` `protected` access instead of `private`.

You're explicitly asking why derived classes can't access private data.  That's by design.

Comment: I am aware of the inaccessibility of `private` base class members. However, please see my comment to PiotrJaszkowski for my unease in using `protected`. May be `protected` is the way to go, I just feel that it break encapsulation.

Comment: @RDK I agree with your comment that it arguably breaks encapsulation.  K-ballo also makes a valid comment that the encapsulation was designed unusually.